# LCD display panel for Ubuntu/RHEL

Tags: linux, lcd, case

I'm looking for a very simple 2 or 3 line LCD display that allows me to print custom data to it from the a linux box (Ubuntu and RHEL).

I want something like [this](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=BB-002-LL&groupid=701&catid=1428&subcat=1429) or [this](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=BB-004-ZA&groupid=701&catid=1428&subcat=1429) that fits in the front of my display case, but instead of fan data or any fancy graphics I just want to be able to print custom data, such as recent Nagios notifications, system load, failed jobs in Jenkins, random jokes, whatever takes my fancy. I can script, and I don't mind figuring out raw commands for USB/serial devices, and the capacity in which the script runs doesn't bother me (Periodically updating or running constantly streaming to/from the device, I don't care, I can deal with it). I also don't mind delving into a proper language like C/C++ to get this to work (Though I'll probably wrap it into a higher level Python module or something friendly).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In today's "Hack-a-day" there was [this entry](http://hackaday.com/2012/02/21/who-couldnt-use-a-little-more-screen-space/) about connecting your parallel port to a simple 2 line LCD screen. Because these small LCD panels have long been standard, its a very simple project, limited only by your creativity.